# SLA if graph API is down

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

I have two questions:

1. How do you subscribe graph API for any down time notification?
2. What is the maximum time limit when graph API down time is expected to be over if it is down? or SLA to fix issues in graph APIs.?

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently there is no health monitoring for graph:
   there is a user voice item that you can vote on and it is under review.
   https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40319329-add-microsoft-graph-api-health-endpoint
2. There is no SLA for microsoft Graph currently. It is a best effort service with no guarantees.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_dipvkudtNm38uiN&Q_CHL=gl
>

Comment: I have up-voted. Please let me know when this fix is released. Thanks for reply!